# How to set a Java mode in CodeMirror editor?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have read CodeMirror User Manual, but I couldn't find how to set mode for JAVA, could you help me?

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code1"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "text/x-csrc",
  matchBrackets: true
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"text/x-java"` is the MIME type used to get the Java mode.

Answer (score 2):

(I know this is answered but I wanted to leave this here for anyone else with the same question we had!)

Each mode lives in a subdirectory of the mode/ directory, and typically defines a single JavaScript file that implements the mode. Loading such file will make the language available to CodeMirror through the [mode option](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_mode), which you declare while creating your CodeMirror instance:

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code1"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "text/x-java",
  matchBrackets: true
});
```

You'll need to ensure your different mode files are added to a mode folder in your library. In your case the java.js file needs to be in a new folder called lib/mode, with a filepath of lib/mode/java.js.

You can inspect each mode's demo page to see what string you must pass to the `mode:` option in order for it to be called. Here's the [java demo](https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/index.html) which also defines all of the "MIME types defined" at the bottom (basically the strings you can use for different java syntaxes).

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of codemirror you can't find the path for java mode, instead you can use c-like mode js file for your purpose.

```js
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("codepane"), {
  mode: "text/x-java",
  indentWithTabs: true,
  smartIndent: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  matchBrackets: true,
  autofocus: true,
  theme: "ambiance",
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.3/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.3/theme/ambiance.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.3/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.3/mode/clike/clike.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="codepane">
  private class InnerClass {
    public int zero() {
      return 0;
    }
  }
</textarea>
```